# scipy.optimize.minimize writes array into array and fails converging

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, minimize

While using scipy.optimize.minimize during a sample problem I encountered an error while minimize function was on it's way to converge to the optimal values. My Code in question is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def get_data_sin(N, sigma_noise=0.1, end=50):
        f = lambda x: np.sin(x/6.)
        x = np.random.rand(N)*end
        y = f(x) + np.random.normal(0, sigma_noise, N)
        return x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1,1)


gitter = lambda N, value: value*np.eye(N)


def rbf(x1, x2, sigma, l):
    return sigma**2 * np.exp(-(0.5/l**2) * np.linalg.norm(x1 - x2)**2)


def get_cov(kernel, X1, X2, param):
    return np.array([[kernel(x1, x2, *param) for x1 in X1] for x2 in X2]) 
    #*param will use all items in param successively
    #list comprehension: expression for item in list


def log_likelihood(hparam, X, y):
    print(hparam)
    sigma, l, sigma_noise = hparam 
    cov = get_cov(rbf, X, X, [sigma, l]) \
        + sigma_noise**2 * np.eye((X.shape[0])) \
        + gitter(X.shape[0], 1e-10)
    ll = -0.5 * np.matmul(y.T, np.linalg.solve(cov,y))
    ll += -np.log( np.linalg.det(np.linalg.cholesky(cov)) )
    return -ll


np.random.seed(seed=100)

N = 30
X, y = get_data_sin(N)

fit = minimize(log_likelihood, (1., 1., 1.,), (X, y))
sigma, l, sigma_noise = fit.x 
print(fit)
```

Where rbf and get_cov functions are used to create a matrix with rbf-like elements, and then are used to calculate the log-likelihood (the function that is supposed to be optimized, should output a scalar).
And since the code outputs values during convergence, I guess that my math is correct. After some time, the output of the hyperparameters (hparam) changes, like so:

```
[ 0.98103018 10.86622839  0.11097829]
[ 0.98103018 10.86622837  0.1109783 ]
[ 0.98103017 10.86622838  0.11097828]
[[ 0.98103018 10.86622837  0.11097828]]
```

where minimize writes a list into a list, so that only one value can be unpacked. This is the error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-7551e417800b> in <module>
     21     return -ll
     22 
---> 23 fit = minimize(log_likelihood, (1., 1., 1.,), (X_train, y_train))
     24 sigma, l, sigma_noise = fit.x

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    592         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    593     elif meth == 'bfgs':
--> 594         return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
    595     elif meth == 'newton-cg':
    596         return _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, **unknown_options)
   1014             alpha_k, fc, gc, old_fval, old_old_fval, gfkp1 = \
   1015                      _line_search_wolfe12(f, myfprime, xk, pk, gfk,
-> 1016                                           old_fval, old_old_fval, amin=1e-100, amax=1e100)
   1017         except _LineSearchError:
   1018             # Line search failed to find a better solution.

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _line_search_wolfe12(f, fprime, xk, pk, gfk, old_fval, old_old_fval, **kwargs)
    853                                      old_fval, old_old_fval,
    854                                      extra_condition=extra_condition,
--> 855                                      **kwargs2)
    856 
    857     if ret[0] is None:

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py in line_search_wolfe2(f, myfprime, xk, pk, gfk, old_fval, old_old_fval, args, c1, c2, amax, extra_condition, maxiter)
    309     alpha_star, phi_star, old_fval, derphi_star = scalar_search_wolfe2(
    310             phi, derphi, old_fval, old_old_fval, derphi0, c1, c2, amax,
--> 311             extra_condition2, maxiter=maxiter)
    312 
    313     if derphi_star is None:

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py in scalar_search_wolfe2(phi, derphi, phi0, old_phi0, derphi0, c1, c2, amax, extra_condition, maxiter)
    432                         _zoom(alpha0, alpha1, phi_a0,
    433                               phi_a1, derphi_a0, phi, derphi,
--> 434                               phi0, derphi0, c1, c2, extra_condition)
    435             break
    436 

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py in _zoom(a_lo, a_hi, phi_lo, phi_hi, derphi_lo, phi, derphi, phi0, derphi0, c1, c2, extra_condition)
    570         # Check new value of a_j
    571 
--> 572         phi_aj = phi(a_j)
    573         if (phi_aj > phi0 + c1*a_j*derphi0) or (phi_aj >= phi_lo):
    574             phi_rec = phi_hi

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py in phi(alpha)
    272     def phi(alpha):
    273         fc[0] += 1
--> 274         return f(xk + alpha * pk, *args)
    275 
    276     if isinstance(myfprime, tuple):

~/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in function_wrapper(*wrapper_args)
    324     def function_wrapper(*wrapper_args):
    325         ncalls[0] += 1
--> 326         return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
    327 
    328     return ncalls, function_wrapper

<ipython-input-55-7551e417800b> in log_likelihood(hparam, X, y)
     11 def log_likelihood(hparam, X, y):
     12     print(hparam)
---> 13     sigma, l, sigma_noise = hparam
     14     cov = get_cov(rbf, X, X, [sigma, l]) \
     15         + sigma_noise**2 * np.eye((X.shape[0])) \

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

For reproduction:
Python version 3.5.2, scipy version 1.3.1, numpy version 1.17.2
Using a fixed seed, seed 42 does not produce the error, seed 100 does. While not using a fixed seed, some random numbers produce the error, some others don't. (I ran the script multiple times, and only every 2 out of 3 or so produced the error.)
The above code ran in a jupyter notebook.

Does anybody know about this behaviour, or can help me identify the problem?

I know of a workaround, using a catchcall and reading the list inside the list element if this happens, still I want to know where this error comes from.

Comment: You give the initial value as a tuple, `(1., 1., 1.,)`, but `minimize` converts it to a 3 element `numpy` array.  Most of the time the shape is (3,), but in the problem instance it becomes (1,3).  I suspect that occurs because the previous call to `log_likelihood` returned an unusual value (it should just be a scalar).

Comment: A easy thing to add would a test or print of `ll` before returning.  Your code in complex enough, that I can't tell what's happening, or might happen, in all cases.  Is there something about the `ll` in one call that triggers this error in the next call?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the hint, I will look into that!

Comment: @hpaulj I have checked, and the dimension of the output of `ll` is always the same, a scalar, as it should be.